# Slaughter houses within Haram boundaries

Tags: hajj, dhabihah, masjid-al-haram

It is well known that `dam e shukar` (also known as al-Hady الهدي) or slaughtering for Hajj is made within the boundaries of the Haram. It is also known that now a days the slaughtering can not be made anywhere, it has to be made within the designated slaughter houses by the government.

I have came to know that [this slaughter house](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Automated+slaughterhouse+in+Makkah/@21.3735383,39.8082071,181m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m14!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xc0a9afc9132e853a!2sAutomated+slaughterhouse+in+Makkah!8m2!3d21.3734768!4d39.8081789!3m6!1s0x0:0xc0a9afc9132e853a!8m2!3d21.3734768!4d39.8081789!9m1!1b1) is being used by some agents for slaughtering for Hajj on behalf of Hajjees.

According to [this picture](https://www.makkahtour.co.uk/blogs/the-boundarieshudood-of-al-haram/), though the exact boundaries are not clear, the slaughter house seems outside the boundaries of Haram. 
Can anybody confirm please.
A bonus question: Where/how can i ask for the local (Makkah) help about traveling in English?

Comment: To me what you claim being known is unclear I don't even get what you mean with boundaries. You may mean al-Haram: The sanctuary in Mekka which is around Mekka and al-Ka'aba but still I don't get what the relevance between it and slaughtering is unless you put some more effort in clarfiying your post.

Comment: @Medi1Saif AlKa'aba, Masjid e Haraam, Hadood e Haram and Meeqat are all different things. have you seen the picture i referred to? The marked boundry in the picture refers to Hadood e Haram and Dam e Shukar must be performed inside this boundary. You cannot slaughter an animal inside the Ka'aba or Masjid e Haraam.

Comment: What is dam e shukar? I've never heard this term.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It is the Slaughtering offered after Rami of 10th Zil Haj for Hajj e Tamattu or Hajj e Qiran. You need to read more about Hajj to get the complete understanding of these terms.

Comment: That's not the issue as this usually is known as hady الهدي -which actually appears in the related qur'an verses (see for example [2:196](https://legacy.quran.com/2/196))- the term is not Arabic and therefore I was not willing to guess whether I was right or wrong.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for letting me know, i was not aware of the arabic of dam e shukar

Answer (score 1):

The slaughter house you have posted first is certainly within the boundary as you may see from your own map the boundary actually is much further west (it is on the highway to Djeddah - the blue mark-). While Mekka is more in the east (at the border of the map I've posted below you may still see the capital "M") and the Masjid al-Haram (The Haram) is more in the North (North/west) at the border of the map I've posted below (close to the right corner you may still read "Al-Haram").

[image]

The boundaries of the sanctuary of Mecca are described in some sources like in imam an-Nawawi's al-Majmo' from which I've quoted them in my answer on [Are non-muslims allowed to visit Mecca?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25499/are-non-muslims-allowed-to-visit-mecca/25503#25503) the ambiguity in the map therein is due to the fact that it excludes mountains (جبل) surrounding it which at least have been natural boundaries in earlier times.
Here some of these which can be found on google maps by searching for "haram boundaries or حد الحرم" which are marked in the area around Mekka:

- On the Highway between Mekka and Djeddah -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Holy+Mosque+Boundary/@21.3575466,39.5301461,39952m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x0:0x788e2d33a7e56eac!8m2!3d21.3523799!4d39.6352816)- (In the west of Mekka).
- In Ash-Shari' -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Haram+Boundary/@21.4853657,39.9393904,858m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x15c1ff804719530d:0x14f88067c65dc4a4!8m2!3d21.4853607!4d39.9415791)- in the east of Mekka.
- On the Laith/Leeth road -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D8%AD%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%E2%80%AD/@21.3338406,39.6493346,3366m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x0:0x76a337a332518a89!8m2!3d21.3327136!4d39.6586704)- in the west (south west) of Mekka.
- The boundary at 'Okaishiyah -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Haram+Boundary+Markings+-+Okaishiyya+Side/@21.3150054,39.7056676,25466m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x0:0xd1b17ffec3f3dd19!8m2!3d21.3168227!4d39.8135519)- in the south west of Mekka.
- The boundary of al-'Awaly close to 'Arafat -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Haram+Boundary+Markings+-+Awali+Side/@21.3517622,39.9323374,8264m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x0:0xf009f82a85a9c676!8m2!3d21.341308!4d39.9398947)- in the south east of Mekka.
- The boundary in direction of al-Hudaibiyyah -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hudaibiyyah+Boundary+Markings/@21.4306457,39.5728119,29214m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x15c2229f3009f0a9:0xe41ea4c908d16aea!8m2!3d21.4306457!4d39.6472979)-.
- And the miqaat for the people of Mekka Masjid 'Aishah -[here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Masjid+Ayesha+Miqat+For+Makkah/@21.4620082,39.7818813,6031m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z2K3YryDYp9mE2K3YsdmF!3m4!1s0x0:0x1372cbe7ad38dde1!8m2!3d21.4676068!4d39.8012781)- which is situated the north of Mekka.

See also [Why masjid Haram is called that name?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/why-masjid-haram-is-called-that-name/29165#29165)

Comment: can you please share the markings on google map instead of that picture with locations in Arabic.

Comment: yes, nut not just one point, the whole circled area as i had shared as "this picture"